# FastCGI - Rewrite - Location with Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I just switched to nginx but I'm having trouble with my URL-Rewriting

I used

```
location /id/ {
       rewrite ^/id/(.*) /index.php?id=$1 break;
}
```

But the php code is not interpreted, worst it's downloaded raw.
Yet .php files are configured as follow:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/my_app$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

What is wrong with my vhost ?

EDIT: Here is the entire vhost 
server {

```
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    server_name  viditx.com www.viditx.com; ## change this to your own domain name

   # I find it really useful for each domain & subdomain to have
   # its own error and access log
    error_log /var/log/nginx/viditx.com.error.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/viditx.com.access.log;
root /var/www/viditx;   

location / {
        # Change this to the folder where you want to store your website
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}
location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
           rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }


    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
            root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            # again, change the directory here to your website's root directory
            # make sure to leave $fastcgi_script_name; on the end!
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Did you read the documentation?](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite)

**break** -> **last**:

```
location /id/ {
    rewrite ^/id/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I guess I have no excuse even though I did read it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

```
location /id/ {
       rewrite '^/id/(.*)$' /index.php?id=$1 break;
}
```

and :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include     /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Have fun !

Comment: Doesn't work. Whenever I go to mywebsite.com/id/abc the php file is still downloaded. If that's any help, I followed this tutorial http://blog.meltingice.net/server-management/setting-up-a-full-web-server-with-nginx-from-start-to-finish/

Comment: Give us your nginx.conf plz

Comment: Edited my question with the entire vhost (without any rewrite) + the conf